# Blob to Jpeg in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently rendering innerHtml to blob in my Angular controller like this:

```
        var blob = new Blob([document.getElementById('exportable').innerHTML]);
```

What I need to know is if there is a way to convert the resulting Blob to a base64 jpeg?

I tried this:

```
            var reader = new window.FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
            var base64data = reader.result;

            base64data = base64data.replace('data:;base64,', 'data:image/png;base64,/9j/')
```

but when I tried to use the result (base64data) I received an error in my Angular controller "Invalid JPEG".

ANY assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to take a screenshot of part of the DOM? I don't think Blob works like that. You may want to look at: https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Comment: Thanks, yes I am,  I tried using html2canvas but I can't get it to work in Angular controller and could not locate a working example where anyone has done it successfully.

Comment: @mcgraphix - Have you seen html2canvas work with Angular?

Comment: Sorry... I have not. I have only tinkered with it. I haven't used it for any real production apps.

Comment: I can get it to append the document to the page as in the examples, but as soon as I try to convert it using todataUrl it errors out.

Comment: If you update the question with what you have so far, someone more familiar with it may be able to help.

Comment: @mcgraphix - Thanks, I truly appreciate your input.